# Is there a C project Default Directory Layout?

Tags: c, styles, project, standards

I've always wanted to know if there is a default directory layout for C projects. You know, which folders should i put which files and such.

So I've downloaded lots of project's source codes on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/) and they were all different than each other.
Generally, I found more or less this structure:

```
    /project         (root project folder, has project name)
    |
    |____/bin        (the final executable file)
    |
    |
    |____/doc        (project documentation)
    |    |
    |    |____/html  (documentation on html)
    |    |
    |    |____/latex (documentation on latex)
    |
    |
    |____/src        (every source file, .c and .c)
    |    |
    |    |____/test  (unit testing files)
    |
    |
    |____/obj        (where the generated .o files will be)
    |
    |
    |____/lib        (any library dependences)
    |
    |
    |____BUGS        (known bugs)
    |
    |____ChangeLog   (list of changes and such)
    |
    |____COPYING     (project license and warranty info)
    |
    |____Doxyfile    (Doxygen instructions file)
    |
    |____INSTALL     (install instructions)
    |        |
    |____Makefile    (make instructions file)
    |
    |____README      (general readme of the project)
    |
    |____TODO        (todo list)
```

Is there a default standard somewhere?

Edit: Sorry, really. I realised there are numerous similar questions for recommended C project directory files. But I've seen people say what they think is best. I'm looking for a standard, something that people usually follow.

Related Questions:

[C - Starting a big project. File/Directory structure and names. Good example required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410243/c-starting-a-big-project-file-directory-structure-and-names-good-example-req)

[Folder structure for a C project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451086/folder-structure-for-a-c-project)

[File and Folder structure of a App/Project based in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407668/file-and-folder-structure-of-a-app-project-based-in-c)

[Project Organization in C Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742391/project-organization-in-c-best-practices)

Comment: I suspect that what you have is as close to a standard as you're going to find.

Comment: So I guess I'll document it and make it the official default! Muhahaha >:D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would say "no", and your empirical evidence seems to support that.

I usually get confused right around when I need to decide between `doc/` and `docs/` ...

Comment: Most of the projects i find prefer 3-letter folders, like doc, cfg (configuration), res (resources) and even tst (for testing).

Comment: @alexdantas I have seen the same thing. It's curious that it's good programming practice to have meaningful names i code but apparently not in the project hierarchy. That said, I do use the short names myself but I also consider it kind of a bad habit.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there is [“libabc”](http://lwn.net/Articles/465093/) which is showcasing common practice.